# How can I get a container (NOT an image) to restart on system startup

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, dockerfile

I want to be able to make changes in a container and if I were to restart my computer, the CONTAINER would restart so it wouldn't be a fresh image in a new container like docker run restart=always does.

Is there an easy way to do this through docker commands similar to the one mentioned above, or do I have to make a script that does a docker start command everytime my system starts?

Comment: You can use `--restart` option when you run the container to provide policy of when the container should restart. https://codeburst.io/how-to-start-docker-containers-automatically-ec0545c392e4

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I saw that and tried that already, but for some reason I can only add the restart on images not containers. At least that's what docker is telling me

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya wait I got it to sort of work.